# Getting a session from my php unto my form page that was submitted via ajax

Tags: php, session

I submitted a form with ajax using a php file url. In the php file, I have validated email already exist and stored the result in a session. Also, I have generated a random id number and stored it in a session as well. Now I want the ajax to bring me these sessions after working on that php file so i can display these sessions on the form page. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance....

PHP

```
include("connection.php");

if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) {

$certification = implode(', ', $_POST['cert_type']);
$documents = implode(', ', $_POST['attached_documents']);

if ($_SESSION['bus_status'] = isset($_POST['bus_status']) ? $_POST['bus_status'] : '') ;
if($_SESSION['bus_status'] == "new"){
    $_SESSION['establishment_year'] = 'null';
    $_SESSION['staff_strength'] = 'null';
}
elseif ($_SESSION['bus_status'] == "existing") {
    $_SESSION['establishment_year'] = $_POST['establishment_year'];
    $_SESSION['staff_strength'] = $_POST['staff_strength'];
}

$numrows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query(" SELECT email FROM personal_data WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."'"));

$string="";
if($numrows!=0){
    $_SESSION['comment'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="font-size: 16px"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Please this user already exists. <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
}
else {

    $_SESSION['rand'] = rand(0, 900);

    $SQL = "INSERT INTO personal_data VALUES (
    '" . $_SESSION['rand'] . "','" . $_POST['firstname'] . "','" . $_POST['surname'] . "','" . $_POST['gender'] . "',

    '" . $_POST['dob'] . "','" . $_POST['age'] . "','" . $_POST['nationality'] . "','" . $_POST['hometown'] . "',

    '" . $_POST['region_of_origin'] . "','" . $_POST['place_of_res'] . "','" . $_POST['region_of_res'] . "','" . $_POST['res_address'] . "',

    '" . $_POST['pos_address'] . "','" . $_POST['mum_nationality'] . "','" . $_POST['dad_nationality'] . "',

    '" . $_POST['mobile_num'] . "','" . $_POST['telephone'] . "','" . $_POST['email'] . "','" . date('d-M-Y h:ia') . "')";

    $result = mysql_query($SQL)
    or die(mysql_error());

    $SQL2 = "INSERT INTO education VALUES (
    '" . $_SESSION['rand'] . "','" . $_POST['level_of_education'] . "','" . $_POST['type_of_education'] . "',

    '" . $_POST['name_of_institution'] . "','" . $_POST['admission_year'] . "','" . $_POST['completion_year'] . "')";

    $result2 = mysql_query($SQL2)
    or die(mysql_error());

    $SQL3 = "INSERT INTO business_information VALUES (
    '" . $_SESSION['rand'] . "','" . $_POST['bus_name'] . "','" . $_POST['bus_description'] . "','" . $_POST['bus_address'] . "',

    '" . $_POST['bus_region'] . "','" . $_SESSION['bus_status'] . "','" . $_SESSION['establishment_year'] . "',

    '" . $_SESSION['staff_strength'] . "','" . $_POST['reg_type'] . "','".$certification."','".$documents."')";

    $result3 = mysql_query($SQL3)
    or die(mysql_error());
}
```

}

AJAX

```
var dataString = $('#appForm').serialize(); //alert (dataString);return false; 
$.ajax({ 
     type: "POST", 
     url: "application_form_params.php", 
     data: dataString, 
     success: function() { 
        window.location.reload(); 
        $('.register-alert').html("You have successfully registered an   applicant"); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your PHP script you can print any data that you want to send:

```
$response = array(
    'rand' => $_SESSION['rand'],
    'establishment_year' => $_SESSION['establishment_year'],
    'staff_strength' => $_SESSION['staff_strength'],
);

echo json_encode($response);
die;
```

And in the JS part process that:

```
var dataString = $('#appForm').serialize(); //alert (dataString);return false; 
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "application_form_params.php", 
    data: dataString, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        window.location.reload(); 
        $('.register-alert').html("You have successfully registered an   applicant with rand " + data.rand); 
    } 
});
```

As an extra advice, please review all your PHP script. As a first point you can start reading about SQL Injection (http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), you should never put in a SQL query the user input directly without filter/escaping it. All input is tainted!

Comment: thank you very much @artberri. Your comment was really helpful

Comment: It will be great if you vote or mark my answer as correct ;)